# Alfresco ошибка при установки postgresql

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

[image: Подскажите с чем связана ошибка?]

Получаю данную ошибку, подскажите как это победить?

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
>   correctly

Comment: в пути к папке, в которую устанавливаете, есть русские символы или пробелы?

Comment: Нет, ставлю сразу на локальный диск

Comment: запускаете установку, правой кнопкой мыши - запустить от имени Администратора?

Comment: да все верно, кстати если запустить по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8080/ то выдает ошибку Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server. (Does this application have access to alfresco-global.properties? Does this application have cross-context permissions?)

Comment: я бы поставил новый виндовс, на виртуалку. И запустил твой инсталятор там. Тогда будет понятно, или система кривая или инсталятор .

Comment: Поставил на виртуалку все заработало как надо) спасибо! как те плюс поставить?)

Comment: благодарю, сейчас ответ оформлю, отметь его как правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для локализации проблемы установи новую систему виндовс, на виртуальную машину. И запустил инсталятор там. Тогда будет понятно, или текущая система кривая или инсталятор.

Если на виртуалке все нормально, значит в твоей системе проблема. Можно попробовать восстановить системные файлы, и тогда инсталятор должен работать.

Запусти командную строку од имени администратора. И выполни команду `sfc /scannow`. Если программа найдет "неправильные" системные файлы, она попросит их заменить оригинальными. Укажи для этого путь к установочному диску с виндовс. Тот с которого устанавливал систему.